# JavaFX WebView execute script doesn´t work

Tags: javascript, java, javafx, webview

My UI is written in HTML and displayed in a JavaFX WebView.

When I click on a HTML button, a JAVA function is called. This works.

But when I directly execute a JavaScript function with the called Java-Function nothing happens. I don't get a error, but nothing happens too.

```
//Javascript
function function1() {
      java.function1java();
}

function function2() {
    java.function2java();
}

//Java
public void function1java() {
    System.out.println("test1");
    webview.getEngine().executeScript("function2();");
}

 public void function2java() {
    System.out.println("test2");
 }
```

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19420753/how-to-call-a-javascript-function-from-a-javafx-webview-on-button-click